# String comparison not as expected

Tags: javascript, jsx

I have written the following code looking for a string token in an array.

```
var parseCSVLines = function(lines) {
    var valueObj = {};
    var delim  = ',';
    var isLayer = false;
    var isGroup = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){

      //skips CR/CF lines
      if(!lines[i]) continue;

      //only data lines reach this loop
      var data = lines[i].split(delim);

      /*********looks for tag*************/
      if(data[0] == '#L' || data[0] == '#l'){
        //on occasions, data[0] is '#L' or '#G' still execution reaches here
        isLayer = true;
      }else if(data[0] == '#G' || data[0] == '#g'){
        isGroup = true;
      }else{
        if(isLayer){
          valueObj[data[0]] = { 
            layerInfo: data[1] == 'on' ? true : false
          };
        }
        else if(isGroup){
          valueObj[data[0]] = { 
            GroupInfo: data[1] == 'on' ? true : false
          };
        }
      }

    }

    return valueObj;
};
```

I loop through lines and mark next line to get data. Weirdly when `data[0]` is `'#L'` and `'#G'`, first `if` statement is executed. What have I done wrong?

Comment: `data[0]` cannot be both `#L` and `#G` at the same time.

Comment: can you just give full code, this much looks fine.

Comment: @Pointy yeah not at the same time well I'll update the full code!

Comment: Can you tell us what you want the output to be?

Comment: You might actually want to do something like `isLayer = /^#L$/i.test(data[0]); isGroup = /^#G$/i.test(data[0])`.

Comment: @RobG should I use a regex for this, cannot it be done using a simple comparison?

Comment: It should work fine - Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/hmdoe3v4/

Comment: @Goku123—you don't have to use a regular expression, it just seems like a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement is fine, even if you have `data[0]='#G#L'`...it will never go into `data[0]=='#L'||data[0]=='#l'`

On my mind you are stuck in the logic-

```
 if (data[0] == '#L' || data[0] == '#l') {
     isLayer = true;
     //isGroup=false; you should toggle isGroup
 } else if (data[0] == '#G' || data[0] == '#g') {
     isGroup = true;
     //isLayer=false; you should toggle isLayer
 } else { //do you want else here??? This would pick the value of isLayer  or isGroup according to previous line processed but not the value according to current line being processed.
     if (isLayer) {
         valueObj[data[0]] = {
             layerInfo: data[1] == 'on' ? true : false
         };
     } else if (isGroup) {
         valueObj[data[0]] = {
             GroupInfo: data[1] == 'on' ? true : false
         };
     }
 }
```

Example:

```
line1: '#L,hi'
line2:'#G,hi'
line3:'hi'
```

processing first line will set `isLayer=true;`

processing second line will set `isGroup=true;//remember isLayer is still true - you haven't set it to false;`

processing third line will trigger your else part...and get into first condition where `if(isLayer)` will be `true`

**To make it work:**

```
//update isLayer and isGroup for every iteration to keep the logic inline
isLayer=(data[0] == '#L' || data[0] == '#l');
isGroup=(data[0] == '#G' || data[0] == '#g');
if(!isLayer && !isGroup) {
     if (isLayer) {
         valueObj[data[0]] = {
             layerInfo: data[1] == 'on' ? true : false
         };
     } else if (isGroup) {
         valueObj[data[0]] = {
             GroupInfo: data[1] == 'on' ? true : false
         };
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(data[0] == "#l" || data[0] == "#L") {
    if(data[0].search("#g") != -1 || data[0].search("#G") != -1){

    }else{
        isLayer = true;
    }
}else if(data[0] == "#g" || data[0] == "#G"){
    if(data[0].search("#l") != 0 || data[0].search("#L") != 0){

    }else{
        is group = true;
    }
}
```

You see, what you weren't doing was checking if both were present. What my code does is checks that

1. The item **is** #g or #l
2. The item is **not** the opposite as well.

This ensures that one, and only one option is chosen.

---

## Good day, And good luck.